# Do.. while loop that calculates the amount of digits in a number doesn't exit (C)

Tags: c, do-while

I'm trying to make a simple program that keeps  asking the user for their credit card number until they have entered a number containing 16 digits. However the do while loop keeps repeating/asking the user for their credit card number. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int card_numb;
int counter;

 do
 {
     counter = 0;
     printf("enter card number:  \n");
     scanf("%d", &card_numb);
     while (card_numb != 0)
    {
      card_numb = card_numb / 10;
      counter++ ;
    }

 }while (counter != 16);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need the external do..while loop, if you intend to run only once?

Comment: You ***can't*** hold a 16-digit card number in a 32-bit `int`. Try printing the number you just entered! Hint: never use an integer type for a card number, phone number, PIN, etc just because it is called a "number". Use a string.

Comment: @SouravGhosh my bad I want the program to keep asking the user for their card number until they input one containing 16 digits.Sorry for the confusion.I edited my original post.

Comment: If you really do want to know whether an integer has 16 digits, assuming you're using a type that can hold numbers of that size (e.g. `long long int`), you don't need a loop: just do `counter >= 1000000000000000LL && counter < 10000000000000000LL`.  But I agree with others that a string is better here.

Answer (score 2):

Typical `int` (signed 32-bit long) can store only upto `2147483647` (10 digits), so it cannot store 16-digit number and the condition `counter != 16` will never be false.

My suggestion is you should treat your credit card number as string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){

    int card_numb[32];
    int valid;

    do
    {
        valid = 1;
        printf("enter card number:  \n");
        if (scanf("%31s", card_numb) != 1)
        {
            fputs("read failed\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if (strlen(card_numb) != 16)
        {
            // wrong length
            valid = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // check if each characters are numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                if (!isdigit((unsigned char)card_numb[i]))
                {
                    // non-number character exists!
                    valid = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }while (!valid);

    return 0;
}
```